# Clear circles in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to remove some circles from a map but isn't working as expected. Here are my code.

Function I have used to draw circles:

```
for (var city in citymap) {
    var circleOptions = {
      map: GoogleMap,
      radius: distance, //In meters
      strokeColor: circleColor,
      fillOpacity: 0.0,
      strokeWeight: circleWeight,
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.

    cityCircle[circleId] = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
}
```

Looking at the cityCircle Array I have eight elements, from 0 to 7. I tryed to remove them using the following function grabbed here stackoverflow forum:

```
function RemoveOverlays(overlays) {
    for (var i = 0; i < overlays.length; i++) {
        overlays[i].setMap(null);
    }
```

I call the function inside of an else if loop like this:

```
else if  (zoom <6 ){
   if (typeof cityCircle[0] !=undefined && cityCircle[0] !=null) {
    RemoveOverlays(cityCircle)
   }
}
```

At the end I have just the latest drawn circle removed. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

---

Here is the entire code.

```
// Listeners for newly created Map
google.maps.event.addListener(GoogleMap, 'center_changed', function() {
      localStorage['CenterLat'] = GoogleMap.getCenter().lat();
      localStorage['CenterLon'] = GoogleMap.getCenter().lng();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(GoogleMap, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      localStorage['ZoomLvl']  = GoogleMap.getZoom();
        var zoom = GoogleMap.getZoom(); //gets zoom level.

        if (SiteCircles && zoom >=6) {
           for (var i=0;i<SiteCirclesDistances.length;i++) {
            for (var circleId=0; circleId < size; circleId++) {
            drawCircle(marker, SiteCirclesDistances[i], circleId); // in meters
            }
           }
        } else if  (zoom <6 ){
               if (typeof cityCircle[index] !="undefined" && cityCircle.length >0) {
                RemoveOverlays(cityCircle)
                }
            }
        });

        // Add home marker if requested
    if (SiteShow && (typeof SiteLat !==  'undefined' || typeof SiteLon !==  'undefined')) {
        for (var city in citymap) {
        var siteMarker  = new google.maps.LatLng(citymap[city].SiteLat, citymap[city].SiteLon);
    var markerImage = circleImage; //Defined on config.js

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteMarker,
            map: GoogleMap,
            icon: {url:markerImage, scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32)},
            title: citymap[city].title,
            zIndex: -99999
         });
    }

function drawCircle(marker, distance, circleId) {
    if (typeof distance === 'undefined') {
        return false;

        if (!(!isNaN(parseFloat(distance)) && isFinite(distance)) || distance < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    distance *= 1000.0;
    if (!Metric) {
        distance *= 1.852;
    }

//Create range circles

    for (var city in citymap) {
          var circleOptions = {
          map: GoogleMap,
      radius: distance, //In meters
      strokeColor: circleColor,
      fillOpacity: 0.0,
      strokeWeight: circleWeight,
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.

    cityCircle[circleId] = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);

  }

}
```

Comment: You wrote `At the end I have just the latest drawn circle removed.` This sounds like typical closure problem but from part of code provided I cannot see it. The other possibility is that you have only one index set. How is `circleId` generated? Could you provide the whole code?

Comment: @AntoJurković The circleId is generated just before I call the drawCircle function in a for loop. `for var circleId=0; circleId < size; CircleId++) { drawCircle(marker, SiteSirclesDistances[i], circleId);`

Comment: @AntoJurković `cityCircle[circleId] = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);` is inside the drawCircle function. I don't get your point, sorry...

Comment: I have found the solution in the follwing solved question.

[google maps v3: clearing a circle made from polylines off the map][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539215/google-maps-v3-clearing-a-circle-made-from-polylines-off-the-map

Answer (score 0):

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator convert type to *String* value so you should check by:

```
typeof cityCircle[0] != "undefined"
```

Comment: My typo in code... After adjusting that line, no circles were removed, even the latest drawn circle. ????

Comment: @user1460038 can you show some live example or more code? Where this `if` statement is, etc... how do you call it? On zoom_change event?

Comment: @user1460038 where you define `cityCircle`?

Comment: I have difined it at the begining of the script using `var cityCircle = new Array(); `.

Comment: That isn't in your 'entire code'.  It would be useful if your 'entire code' was the entire code required to replicate the problem including the HTML markup.

Comment: @geocodezip I'm sorry..That was a portion of the entire code, where I draw and try to remove the circles, not the complete code that is larger than that and in three file config.js, extension.js and the main script file.